# NPM Link to Src Dir Instead of Lib Dir

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, symlink, npm-link

I'm working on several NPM modules at a time - there is one main module that imports three others. I have used `npm link` to link the others to the main module, however I am writing all the modules using Babel to transpile the source. When I build one of the modules I run `npm run build` which runs the transpilation and compiles the files in the modules `src` directory to its `lib` directory. However, because each of the modules' package.json file specifies the main file location as `lib/index.js` this means that for a linked module to appear updated to my main module, I always need to build it.

Is there any way (when using `npm link`) to have it link to the `src` dir instead of the `lib` dir? Failing that, is there a better way to achieve what I want - to see updates to the linked modules code reflected instantly in the main module?

Comment: You can use webpack alias in this tutorial https://medium.com/@bmihelac/tips-for-local-developing-of-react-modules-with-babel-and-webpack-51f9c2f0477

Answer (score 4):

1) An easy way to resolve this is to temporarily change the entry point in your library module's `package.json` when developing:

```
/* library-module/package.json */
{
  "main": "src/index.js",
  ...
}
```

Now wherever you `npm link library-module`, you should be loading the library module's `src/index.js`

2) Alternatively, you can setup a watch task to always build to `lib` after detecting changes in `src`. This way, your new changes will always be reflected in your consuming module.